# How can I terminate a Python script manually without interrupting file output?

Tags: python, terminate

I am somewhat new to Python, so I imagine this question has a simple answer. But I cannot seem to find a solution anywhere.

I have a Python script that continually accepts input from a streaming API and saves the data out to a file.

My problem when I need to stop the script to modify the code. If I use ctrl-f2, I sometime catch the script while it is in the process of writing to the output file, and the file ends up corrupted.

Is there a simple way to stop Python manually that allows it to finish executing the current line of code?

Comment: This sounds like a problem for the [`signal`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/signal.html) and [`atexit`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/atexit.html) modules. That said, you might want to consider a transactional database for saving the data.

Comment: I would second atexit ...

Comment: Thanks. Though I should have specified in the question that I'm using Pycharm's "stop" button to kill the script. And it does not appear it is capable of being caught, since it sends a sigkill signal.

Is there another way of stopping a script that would send a different signal? I've tried Ctrl-C and it does not seem to work with Pycharm.

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the `SIGTERM` or `SIGINT` signal and set a global variable that your script routinely checks to see if it should exit.  It may mean you need to break your operations up into smaller chunks so that you can check the exit variable more frequently

```
import signal

EXIT = False

def handler(signum, frame):
    global EXIT
    EXIT = True

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handler)


def long_running_operation():
    for i in range(1000000):
        if EXIT:
            # do cleanup or raise exception so that cleanup
            # can be done higher up.
            return
        # Normal operation.
```

Comment: Thanks. Though it looks like Pycharm's Stop button sends a sigkill signal, which this method would not catch.

Do you know if there is another way of stopping a Python script that would send a catchable signal?

Comment: If you're running it from a shell, CTRL-C will send a SIGINT